# tensorflow_datasets installation issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, environment

I installed the following packages and was trying to import them

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

but I have been getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\MNIST.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import tensorflow_datasets.core.logging as _tfds_logging
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import community
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\community\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core.community.huggingface_wrapper import mock_builtin_to_use_gfile
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\community\huggingface_wrapper.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import dataset_builder
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import split_builder as split_builder_lib
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\split_builder.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import writer as writer_lib
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\writer.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.core import shuffle
  File "C:\Users\olani\Downloads\DATA SCIENCE\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\shuffle.py", line 20, in <module>
    import resource
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'
```

I have updated my tensorflow, checked my python version. In fact, I uninstalled and reinstalled my python. I have tried python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11 but still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi @olaniyi  Please let us know the python and tensorflow version installed in your system. Could you also verify with this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) that you have followed all the steps properly to install tensorflow with conda environment